# linux command ' symbol

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, command-prompt, symbols

In linux command prompt(terminal) , I accidentally typed ' symbol, then the terminal is printing with prompt > .

Like this

```
gaian@gaian-lap057:~$ '
>
```

I want to know, what this symbol(') represents and what happens if we keep on typing on the (>) prompt.

If anyone this please share with me.

Comment: It is a quote, starting a string; the prompt is reminding you that you should terminate the string (with another single quote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting a string with single quotes (`'`) allows you to protect it from shell expansion. E.g., `grep '*' myfile.txt` allows you to search the file for the `*` character instead of the shell expanding it to the list of files in the current directory.

The `>` is the just the prompt for a multi-lined string. Until you terminate the quoting with another `'`, it won't be passed down to the shell.

Answer (score 1):

It just means that you started a quoted string, which can contain line breaks. If you type another `'` character, the quotation is finished. Pressing return then will most likely tell you that this command doesn't exist.